# Web code is just not working - text keeps popping up after animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I'm trying to animate three phrases to zoom and fade in, then fade out consecutively, with an infinite loop. But after the first loop iteration the text pops up with 100% opacity for a few seconds then suddenly disappears after animation is complete.

It does not do this if I play the animations only once.

See GIF: https://i.gyazo.com/24574a5112f8920ce1a37a2fa65f4a40.gif

Here's the source code:

```
<div class="anim-box">
  <h4 class="loop-phrase" id="move">Move Better</h4>
  <h4 class="loop-phrase" id="heal">Heal Faster</h4>
  <h4 class="loop-phrase" id="live">Live Longer</h4>
</div>
```

```
.anim-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.loop-phrase {
  font-size: 24px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
}

#move {
  animation: move 2s linear;
}

#heal {
  animation: heal 2s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#live {
  animation: live 2s linear;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes heal {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes live {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```
function animateText() {
  const moveText = document.getElementById('move');
  const healText = document.getElementById('heal');
  const liveText = document.getElementById('live');

  let counter = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      moveText.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        moveText.style.opacity = 1;
        moveText.style.animation = 'none';
        void moveText.offsetWidth;
        moveText.style.animation = 'move 2s linear';
        counter++;
      }, 1000);
    } else if (counter === 1) {
      healText.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        healText.style.opacity = 1;
        healText.style.animation = 'none';
        void healText.offsetWidth;
        healText.style.animation = 'heal 2s linear';
        counter++;
      }, 1000);
    } else if (counter === 2) {
      liveText.style.opacity = 0;
      setTimeout(() => {
        liveText.style.opacity = 1;
        liveText.style.animation = 'none';
        void liveText.offsetWidth;
        liveText.style.animation = 'live 2s linear';
        counter = 0;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, 3000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  animateText();
};
```

Tried to adjust the opacity to be 0% during the 1 second delay in between text animations to no avail. I am really stuck.

Comment: You set the opacity to 1. Then you set it to 0 but when counter is 0 which will happen after a few iterations

Comment: Setting an inline style has greater 'selectivity' than any setting via a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```js
const animateText = () => {
            const text = document.getElementById("text");
            let counter = 0;
            setInterval(() => {
                switch (counter) {
                    case 0:
                        text.textContent = "Move Better"
                        counter++
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        text.textContent = "Heal Faster"
                        counter++
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        text.textContent = "Live Longer"
                        counter = 0;
                        break
                    default:
                }
            }, 3000);

        };
    //animateText()
```

```css
.body {
    background-color: black;
}

.anim-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 200px;
}

.loop-phrase {
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
}

#text {
    animation: text 3s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="loop-phrase" id="text"></h4>
```